# How to update on click custom directive in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-directives

I am writing a v-mailto directive for use in electron to wrap up the shell.openExternal commands with an easy v-mailto:{email, body, subject} style directive

This is what I have so far:

isObject is lodash function, isEmpty is my own to check for empty string, false, [], {}

```js
Vue.directive('mailto',
  {
    inserted: (el, binding, vnode) => {
      el.addEventListener('click', async e => {
        let finalString = ''
        let body = ''
        let subject = ''
        let email = ''
        if (isObject(binding.value)) {
          if (!isEmpty(binding.value.email)) {
            email = binding.value.email
          }
          if (binding.value.message || binding.value.msg || binding.value.body) {
            body = 'body=' + encodeURIComponent(binding.value.message || binding.value.msg || binding.value.body)
          }
          if (!isEmpty(binding.value.subject)) {
            subject = 'subject=' + binding.value.subject
          }
          finalString = `mailto:${email}?${subject}&${body}` //building the string properly is a work in progress
        } else {
          const emailAddress = binding.value
          if (!isEmpty(emailAddress)) {
            finalString = `mailto:${emailAddress}`
          }
        }
        if (!isEmpty(finalString)) {
          shell.openExternal(finalString)
        } else {
          console.error('mailto failed')
        }
      })
    }
  })
```

My question is, how do I make this respond and update for changes to the binding?  For example, the developer has something like this

```html
<a v-mailto="{email: 'test@test.test', subject: 'hello', body: mailBody }">Send Email</a>
```

...

```js
data(){
   return {
      mailBody:''
   }
},
mounted(){
 // do some kind of async logic
 this.mailBody='hello world'
}
```

Therefore changing the value of the mailBody after the directive has already been run and finished the inserted?  I know directives have `update` but I am unsure how to use it for this.

-- Edit
I had to make a component for this instead.  Still hoping to fix the directive version as this version makes it difficult to allow a click event in the slot like a button to change the mailto props after mailto has run because events start from the child and pop upwards to the parent.  So you can't easily say send email -> clear form without a $nextTick() to trick it into running the parent click event before the child finishes.

```html
<template>
    <span @click="mailTo">
      <slot></slot>
    </span>
</template>

<script>
import { shell } from 'electron'
import { isEmpty } from './utils'

export default {
  name: 'Mailto',
  props: {
    email: String,
    body: String,
    subject: String
  },
  methods: {
    mailTo () {
      const body = encodeURIComponent(this.body)
      const subject = this.subject
      const email = this.email
      let finalString = `mailto:${email}`
      if (!isEmpty(body) || !isEmpty(subject)) {
        finalString += '?'
      }
      if (!isEmpty(subject)) {
        finalString += `subject=${subject}&`
      }
      if (!isEmpty(body)) {
        finalString += `body=${body}&`
      }
      if (!isEmpty(finalString)) {
        shell.openExternal(finalString)
      } else {
        console.error('mailto failed')
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```